# How do I map a certain input in bash to a command?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

So I was wondering if it is possible for me to map a certain input to a command in gnome terminal. For example, when I type "foo" in the command shell, it would automatically execute a certain command like going to a directory where a program is located and execute that program in a specific configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is called an [alias](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html):

> A Bash alias is essentially nothing more than a keyboard shortcut, an
>   abbreviation, a means of avoiding typing a long command sequence. If,
>   for example, we include alias lm="ls -l | more" in the ~/.bashrc file,
>   then each lm [1] typed at the command-line will automatically be
>   replaced by a ls -l | more. This can save a great deal of typing at
>   the command-line and avoid having to remember complex combinations of
>   commands and options. Setting alias rm="rm -i" (interactive mode
>   delete) may save a good deal of grief, since it can prevent
>   inadvertently deleting important files.

So basically:

```
alias foo="cd /path/to/dir; ./myprogram; cd -"
```

`cd -` is following @Cyrus's suggestion - to return you to the directory you started from. This is safer and more expected of most commands, but of course, you can use whatever you like.

Comment: @Cyrus Good suggestion, added.